# VBA find the positional coordinates of the found value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this simple `macro` that goes to the location where a value is.

```
Sub dkdk()
    Dim dk As String
    Dim rng
    dk = "Document Type"
    If Trim(dk) <> "" Then
        With Sheets(1).Range("1:10")
            Set rng = .Find(dk, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, _
            False)
            Application.Goto rng, True
            If  Then

            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

How can i take in a `msgbox` the location i.e. `Cells(x,y)` of the value in the `Excel` grid?

Comment: Is this what you want? `Msgbox rng.Address`

Comment: Yesssss you can post an answer so i can mark it if you want. I didn't know it was that simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Sub dkdk()
    Dim dk As String
    Dim rng As Range

    dk = "Document Type"

    If Trim(dk) <> "" Then
        With Sheets(1).Range("1:10")
            Set rng = .Find(dk, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, _
                      xlByRows, xlNext, False)

            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto rng, True
                '<~~ This will give something like $A$1
                MsgBox rng.Address 
                '<~~ This will give something like Cells(1,1)
                MsgBox "Cells(" & rng.Row & "," & rng.Column & ")"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you both for your wonderful contribution! I will mark on ~5min thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

before the Application.Goto statement, insert the following:

```
msgbox "rownumber: " & rng.row & ", columnnumber: " & rng.column
```

and, if you like to error check:

```
if not rng is nothing then
    msgbox "rownumber: " & rng.row & ", columnnumber: " & rng.column
end if
```

Comment: Thank you both for your wonderful contribution! Please keep this answer as it's contents are needed. I said to Rout i will mark his question but your is also valuable!